# How to add EventListener for dynamic contents in iphone

Tags: iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile, addeventlistener

I am developing iphone application in Titanium. Unable to set `addEventListener` to my dynamically receiving contents.

Here is my code:

```
var receivedAccountsLength = Ti.App.userAccounts.length;

var topFrom = 100;
for(var i=1;i<receivedAccountsLength;i++)
{
    var cont = Ti.UI.createLabel({text: Ti.App.userAccounts[i].accountName , width: 100, height: 30, borderWidth: 1, top: topFrom });   
    win.add(cont);  

    cont.addEventListener('click', function()
    {
        alert("cont");
    });

    topFrom += 50;
}
```

can any one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@suresh Try this code this is Absolute working for you.
first you get your "eventListener object" then you can get you its property, 
for help just Copy paste this code

```
 var receivedAccountsLength = Ti.App.userAccounts.length;

    var topFrom = 100;
    for(var i=1;i<receivedAccountsLength;i++)
    {
        var cont = Ti.UI.createLabel({text: Ti.App.userAccounts[i].accountName , width: 100, height: 30, borderWidth: 1, top: topFrom });   


        cont.addEventListener('click', function(event)
        {
            alert("cont : "+ event.source.text);
        });
        win.add(cont);  
        topFrom += 50;
    }
```

If, working the enjoy Titanium .....Cheers...!

Comment: you try custom this code like 

for(var i=1;i<receivedAccountsLength;i++) replace with "for(var i=1;i<10;i++)"

and 
text: Ti.App.userAccounts[i].accountName Replace with text:"Name "+i

Comment: Thanks for ur help. But,sorry. i unable to get alert message.

Comment: when you click then, you not got any alert message i'm right

plz, send me your code (for....)